# How to update $scope.items array order in response to user re-sorting the DOM array using Angular-UI ui-sortable directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ui-sortable directive (from angular-ui ) in the view

```
<ul ui-sortable>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" >
     {{item.property1}}
     {{item.property2}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

As a result the user can drag and drop to re-sort the items in the browser but this does not update the order of the $scope.items array. How can this be accomplished so that $scope.items array order stays in sync with user initiated drag and drop change in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Missing 
**ng:model**

```
<ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">
        <li ng:repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Please check below working example

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/)</kbd>

It display the updated array

```
<div ng:repeat="item in list">{{item}}</div>
```

Array is updated automatically by the directive

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks for the quick response and the demo fiddle.

Comment: btw, would you be interested in working on a angularjs project on a freelance basis?